# OSX Xamarin App Enetitlements file application identifier error

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin

I've been facing this issue for a little while now. I'm developing an OSX application with Xamarin, and I'm attempting to upload it to the app store through XCode.

I've got my certificates set up and installed, but when I go to validate the archive through organizer I get this error which lists an identifier issue.

[image: error]

I've deleted and recreated all of my certificates, and still i am facing this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else viewing this, I stopped attempting to do certificates manually and have simply allowed xcode to sign my packages automatically.